# Remove duplicates in multifasta, where entries are paired

Tags: python, bash, awk

Hi my input looks like:

```
>ref 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>sample1 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>sample2 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
```

The entries in the fasta file are paired so that the ref is paired with the sample# below it.

I want to identify where the nt seqeunce for sample# and ref are identical, and remove them from the fasta (or put them into another fasta file of their own). The output would hopefully be a fasta file where the nt sequences for refs and sample# are different.

So far I have tried seqkit rmdup command, however, this doesn't treat the entries as if they are paired. How can I accomplish this, ideally with a bash command or other program.

Comment: please show the actual code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output ... making sure both sets of output correspond to the sample input; please also insure the sample input shows both cases ... a match/duplicate ... a non-match/non-duplicate ... so we can understand the differences in the two cases

Comment: Being unfamiliar with the fasta data structure, how is this data paired?  Can you post a small sample of the actual format?

Comment: @JonSG Here is a good description. https://biojulia.net/BioSequences.jl/v0.5/io/fasta/#:~:text=FASTA%20is%20a%20text%2Dbased,name%2C%20description%2C%20and%20sequence.

Comment: or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:
Make a list from every two records (4 lines), each line an element of the list. Then compare DNA sequences in each list. If they are not equal, print the ref and sample.

**Note:** This script assumes that your FASTA record is a two line record (as in your example), not wrapped into multi line FASTA. If you have wrapped FASTA record, you need to convert it to two line records, or I suggest you parse your FASTA file with Biopython Module.

```
counter =0 
my_records =[]
with open("input.fasta") as f:
    for line in f:
        counter+=1
        my_records.append(line.strip())

        if counter % 4 == 0:
            if my_records[1] != my_records[3]:
                [print(item) for item in my_records]
            my_records =[]
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk script seems to solve your problem.  If it does, please mark this as correct.  If it does not, please post a comment.

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat fastaScrubber-v0.awk
{
  if(NR%4==2){
    ref=$0
  }else if(NR%4==3){
    samN=$0
  }else if(NR%4==0){
    sam=$0
    if(sam!=ref){
      printf(">ref\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",ref ,samN ,sam)
    }
  }
}
Mac_3.2.57$cat fasta0 | awk '{if(NR%4==2||NR%4==0){print}}' | uniq -c
   2 GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
   2 GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAB
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
   1 GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAXC
   1 GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAC
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAXC
   1 GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAC
Mac_3.2.57$awk -f fastaScrubber-v0.awk fasta0
>ref
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>sample2 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>ref
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
>sample4 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
>ref
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAXC
>sample5 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAC
>ref
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAXC
>sample6 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAC
Mac_3.2.57$cat fasta0
>ref 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>sample1 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>sample2 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>ref 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAB
>sample3 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAB
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
>sample4 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAB
>ref 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAXC
>sample5 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAC
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAXC
>sample6 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAC
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate `awk` solution via `bash` script:

Pass the fasta file to be processed as a parameter to the script execution.  For lines that start with `>ref` capture that line into variable `rtag` and the following line into the variable `rtag`.  For lines that start with `>sample` capture that line into the variable `stag` and the following line into the variable `s`.  If `r` does not equal `s` print  all four captured lines as formatted line.

```
#!/bin/bash

fasta="${1:-input.fasta}"

awk '
/^>ref/{rtag=$0; getline r}
/^>sample/{
    stag=$0; getline s
    if(r!=s){
        printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", rtag, r, stag, s
    }
}
' "$fasta"
```

Output:

```
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>sample2 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
```

input.fasta contents:

```
>ref 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>sample1 
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAA
>ref 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
>sample2 
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAAT
```